# Add new library in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include, include-path

I have just downloaded a library and I want to use it in my programs in C++ (Visual studio 2012).

In searching "How to add a library to VC++ project" I found 3 main action should be done:
"Right click on project name in solution explorer/ select properties/ in "project property page" window add library address in 3 places...

1. C/C++ /General/ Additional Include directories
2. Linker/General/Additional Library directories
3. Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies."

Question1: When I do first one I can use library, is it essential to add path in second and third one?
Question2:what is difference between them?
Question3:Is there any other thing to do for adding a lib. to project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when you use a third-party library, you need two things:

1. The header files that include the library's function declarations (compilation step)
2. The .lib file itself (linker step)

The *Additional Include Directories* entry only solves problem #1. It doesn't solve the linking step, which is solved by items #2 and #3 from your list.